# Add 1 to z-index onclick for IE compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I'm putting together a map using Raphael. What I have so far works in Chrome and Firefox, but how can I make this compatible with IE? Here's a link to my test map. http://www.imsmfg.com/imsepracks/sales-reps.php

Here's the javascript:

```
st[0].onclick = function () {       
    var maxZ = Math.max.apply(null,$.map($("#paper > *"), function(e,n){
           if($(e).css("position")=="absolute")
                return parseInt($(e).css("z-Index"))||1 ;
           })
    );

    document.getElementById(current).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById(current).style.zIndex = maxZ+1;

    current = state;
};
```

Comment: Why is it not compatible with IE at the moment? What problems/errors are you getting?

Comment: In IE the div containing my information doesn't show onclick.

Comment: By the div you mean the one containing the contact information. right?

Comment: yup! The css selector I use is compatible with IE, so I don't know what other error is occurring with the script that it's not showing.

Answer (score 0):

I get an error in my IE console on IE8:
Object doesn't support this property or method - line 31 in imsep.js

```
   $(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
        });
```

From what i have seen, the problem lies with setting display:block; so it might be related to this js error.

Edit:
When i set display block manually via the ie dom inspector, i see the div.

Edit2:
I don't find #accordion on your page, you may want to do something like:

```
$(function() {
      if($("#accordion").length > 0)
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                navigation: true,
                active: false,
                collapsible: true
            });
    });
```

Comment: Just debugged the accordion and changed a few other things to use if. This was useful but not an answer to my current question. Thanks though!

Comment: I don't get the error in ie anymore, but i still think the issue is with `document.getElementById(current).style.display = 'block'` Try `alert(current)` before this line and see if it is right.

Comment: Okay. alert(current) does not work in IE, but works in Firefox and Chrome. Is there a different method I can use to "getElementById" since it doesn't work in IE?

Comment: It works in ie, but there most be something with how you set `state` and `current`. It may be (but i am very unsure) that the problem lies when you bind the mouseover / mouseout events, maybe they don't fire. I would put some alerts everywhere you change/set `current` to find the actual bug.

Comment: I mean, getElementById works in ie, but `current` may be still null

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can tell you is that in IE an element appearing lower in the markup (but not a child of the same parent) will always have higher z-index. 
There are two possible solutions to that:

1) rework you code to not rely on z-index (`absolute` positioned elements should always appear over top of the `relative` or `static` ones anyway)

2) physically move your positioned div at the bottom of the document body.

Also your `maxZ` calculations looks awkward and messy. Are you sure `max()` actually works with arbitrary array of values (i.e. with number of elements more than 2)? In IE, more specifically.

If you need more help, post your markup.

Comment: Instead of using the z-index, I can toggle in divs with jQuery. But now my problem is how to make it work with Raphael. Here's a test page that works: http://www.imsmfg.com/imsepracks/test.html